# Unable to cast object of type ''System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

When I want to get value from DataGrid selected row I had error Unable to cast object of type ''System.Xml.Linq.XElement'  to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.
Date in DataGrid is load from XML file.
C#:

```
foreach (DataRowView row in dataGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    string text = row.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[person]}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="331" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1130" FontSize="14" FontFamily="SimSun">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[name].Value}"  />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[date].Value}"  />


                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Is there another possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bound the `ItemsSource` property to an `IEnumerable<XElement>`, you won't get any `DataRowView` objects from the `SelectedItems` collection. These are `XElements` and nothing else.

How to get the value of an `XElement` depends on how your XML data is structured, but the following sample code should give you the idea:

```
foreach (var row in dataGrid.SelectedItems.OfType<XElement>())
{
    XElement nameElement = row.Element("name");
    if(nameElement != null)
    {
        string name = nameElement.Value;
    }
}
```